# Can't retrieve data from database using onClick event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I've been working on a school project for my state exam and I've encountered some problems with getting data from the database with a php file.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Programma Scolastico</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Immagini/icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/CssSitoWeb.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/animate.min.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Js/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
        <script src="Js/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
        <script src="Js/app.js"></script>

        <div id="background">
            <div id="in-back">
                <span class="title">Programma 5AIA</span>
                </br><button id="column-opener">Vade</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="paragraph-column">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the php file which gives problem ( Undefined index: idMateria -- line 5)

ElencoArgomentiByMaterie.php:

```
<?php
    include 'CredenzialiAccesso.php';
    $conn = new PDO ($str, $user, $pwd);
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM Argomento WHERE Materia_idMateria = :idMat")
    $stmt -> bindValue(':idMat', $_GET["idMateria"]);
    if ($stmt -> execute())
    {
        echo json_encode($stmt -> fetchAll());
    }
?>
```

Here's the function which create the buttons used to trigger onClick event:

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $(function ()
    {
        $('.title').textillate(
        {
            in: {effect: 'rollIn'}
        });
    })
$("#column-opener").click(function()
    {
        $("#background").animate({left: '272px'});
        $("#in-back").animate({right: '125px'});
        $("#column-opener").hide();

        $.getJSON( "Php/ElencoMaterie.php", function(res)
        {
            var form = $('<form></form>');
            $.each(res, function(k, v)
            {
                var input = $('<input type="button" onclick="ArgomentoByMateria('+v['idMateria']+')" value="'+ v['nomeMateria'] +'" id="buttonMateria"/>');
                //var input = $('<input type="button" value="' + v['nomeMateria'] + '" id="buttonMateria" />');
                form.append(input);
            });
            $("#paragraph-column").empty().append(form);
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the function triggered while clicking:

```
function ArgomentoByMateria(idMat)
{
    $.getJSON("Php/ElencoArgomentiByMaterie.php", {'idMateria':idMat}, function(res)
    {
        $("#in-back").animate({right: '50px'});
        $("#in-back").css("margin", "130px 100px 50px 250px");
        $("#in-back").animate({top: '30px'});
        //$("#in-back").css("margin-top" , "50px");
        $("span").css("font-size" , "50px");

        if (res.length > 0)
        {
            $.each(res, function(k, v)
            {
                var row = $('<span>'+v['descrizione']+'</span> <button onclick="SottoArgomentoByArgomento('+v['idArgomento']+')" value="+"/></ br>');
                //var row = $('<span>'+v['descrizione']+'</span></ br>');
            });
            $("#in-back").append(row);
        }
    });
}
```

ElencoMaterie.php:

```
<?php
    include 'CredenzialiAccesso.php';
    $conn = new PDO ($str, $user, $pwd);
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT nomeMateria FROM Materia");
    if ($stmt -> execute())
    {
        echo json_encode($stmt -> fetchAll());
    }
?>
```

PS: Sorry for bad english.

Comment: in getJson you call `ElencoArgomentiByMaterie.php` but the filename is `ElencoArgomentiMateria.php`? just a typo here?

Comment: Yeah I should have fixed it now, was an error in the question. Anyway, can't understand which variable should i initialize.

Comment: The error is in the bindValue line, not in an echo line, like the link you gave.

Comment: check what you receive from getJson. so do a `var_dump($_GET)` and a `var_dump($_POST)`. If you got nothing there, check if you get smth in `function ArgomentoByMateria(idMat)` as `idMat`, so do a console.log(idMat) there, ...

Comment: myguess is that you don't get what you expect for `v` in your first `$.each` in first place. So there original error could already be in `ElencoMaterie.php`

Comment: Actually tried with a breakpoint in the getjson line and idMat is undefined

Comment: there you go. continue debugging this way until you find where the error starts.

Comment: Solved: error in the query inside ElencoMaterie.php | didn't SELECT idMateria, I just selected nomeMateria instead.

Comment: since you solved it and it had nothing to do with the original question and that question was marked as dublicatate anyway, you might want to delete the question at all...